# SFINAE | strange behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am studying SFINAE and c++ in general. I'm having a strange behaviour with My SFINAE macros (called here "annotations"):

**<lang/Annotations.h>**

```
#pragma once
#define ENABLE_IF(y) typename std::enable_if<y,std::nullptr_t>::type
#define IS_REFERENCE(x) std::is_reference<x>::value
#define IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(...) std::is_constructible<__VA_ARGS__>::value
```

---

I made a custom "`MY_OBJECT`" class, which provides the following constructor:

```
MY_OBJECT(const char* stringDataPtr) noexcept;
```

The objective here is the following:

> By using a variadic template function, each template argument's type must be checked: if it can be passed to `String` constructor (`std::is_constructible`) then a message "is constructible" must be printed, otherwise "is not constructible" must be printed.

---

**The problem**

Even by passing `int` values, my SFINAE method does not get "SFINAE'd" and I always get "Is constructible" message.

---

**<util/SFINAETools.h**

```
namespace SFINAETools {

    enum class SFINAEResult {
        IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE,
        IS_NOT_CONSTRUCTIBLE,
        IS_REFERENCE,
        IS_NOT_REFERENCE
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const SFINAEResult& value) {
    
        static std::unordered_map<SFINAEResult, System::MyString> strings {
            {SFINAEResult::IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE, "IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE"},
            {SFINAEResult::IS_NOT_CONSTRUCTIBLE, "IS_NOT_CONSTRUCTIBLE"},
            {SFINAEResult::IS_REFERENCE, "IS_REFERENCE"},
            {SFINAEResult::IS_NOT_REFERENCE, "IS_NOT_REFERENCE"}
        };
        return out << strings[value];
    }

    class SFINAECallbackHandler : public Object {
    public:
        virtual void onSFINAEResult(const SFINAEResult& result) const = 0;
    };

    template <typename... ARGS, ENABLE_IF(IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(ARGS...))>
    void executeIfConstructible(const SFINAECallbackHandler& callBackHandler) {

        callBackHandler.onSFINAEResult(SFINAEResult::IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE);
    }

    template <typename... ARGS, ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(ARGS...))>
    void executeIfConstructible(const SFINAECallbackHandler& callBackHandler) {

        callBackHandler.onSFINAEResult(SFINAEResult::IS_NOT_CONSTRUCTIBLE);
    }

    template <typename X, ENABLE_IF(IS_REFERENCE(X))>
    void executeIfIsReference(const SFINAECallbackHandler& callBackHandler) {

        callBackHandler.onSFINAEResult(SFINAEResult::IS_REFERENCE);
    }

    template <typename X, ENABLE_IF(!IS_REFERENCE(X))>
    void executeIfIsReference(const SFINAECallbackHandler& callBackHandler) {

        callBackHandler.onSFINAEResult(SFINAEResult::IS_NOT_REFERENCE);
    }
};
```

**MAIN.cpp**

```
#include <lang/CppApplication.h>
#include <util/SFINAETools.h>

class MyCallbackHandler :public SFINAETools::SFINAECallbackHandler {

public:

    virtual void onSFINAEResult(const SFINAETools::SFINAEResult& result) const override {

        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
};

class MY_OBJECT : public Object {
public:

    MY_OBJECT(const char* strDataPtr) {

    }
};
class Main : public CppApplication {

public:

    virtual int main(const std::vector<String>& arguments) override {

        createString(1, "2");
        return 0;
    }

    template <typename Arg1>
    void createString(Arg1&& arg1) {

        SFINAETools::executeIfConstructible<MY_OBJECT, Arg1>(MyCallbackHandler());
    }

    template <typename Arg1, typename ...Args>
    void createString(Arg1&& arg1, Args&&... args) {

        createString(arg1);
        createString(args...);
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    void createString(Args&&... args) {

        std::list<MY_OBJECT> list;
        createString(list, args...);
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const SFINAEResult& value)` function does not make much sense. You declare a static variable but every time the function is called, you try to insert items in it. So in the end that function is **less efficient** that a foreach loop over a static C style array or even nested if...

Comment: good point, how would you enable the conversion from enum to string literal?

Comment: I don't know `HashMap` but with `std::unordered_map` one could use initilizer list which is easy to use, read and also efficient. As the initialisation is done when constructing the object, it will works as expected with minimal noise in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is the problem (the only problem) but this macro

```
#define ENABLE_IF(y) typename std::enable_if<y>::type
```

becomes `void` when `y` is true.

So when `y` is true

```
template <typename... Types, ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(Types...)) = 0>
```

becomes

```
template <typename... Types, void = 0>
```

That can't work. `0` isn't a valid value for `void`. There are no valid values for `void`.

And

```
template <typename X, ENABLE_IF(IS_REFERENCE(X))>
```

becomes

```
template <typename X, void>
```

That is even worse.

I suppose you can define `ENABLE_IF` to return (in this case) an `int`

```
// ...........................................VVVVV
#define ENABLE_IF(y) typename std::enable_if<y, int>::type
```

remembering the `= 0` after every `ENABLE_IF`

---

Another problem: now you have

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
static bool executeIfConstructible(std::function<void()> predicate) {

    predicate();
    return true;
}

template <typename X, typename Y , ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y))>
static bool executeIfConstructible(std::function<void()> predicate) {

    return false;
}
```

So you have two version of `executeIfContructible()`: the first one always enabled, the second one enabled only when `!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y)` is true.

You have to disable the first one when `!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y)` is false (when `IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y)`) or you'll have an ambiguous call when the second one is enabled.

```
template <typename X, typename Y , ENABLE_IF(IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y))>
static bool executeIfConstructible(std::function<void()> predicate) {
    predicate();
    return true;
}

template <typename X, typename Y , ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE(X,Y))>
static bool executeIfConstructible(std::function<void()> predicate) {
    return false;
}
```

---

Unrequested suggestion: C-style macros are distilled evil. Avoid C-style macros when you can.

For example, instead a macro for `ENABLE_IF`, define a `using`

```
 template <bool B>
 using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<B, int>::type;
```

For `IS_REFERENCE` and `IS_CONSTRUCTIBLE`—if you are sure you need them—you can define (starting from C++14) a couple of `constexpr` template variables

```
 template <bool B>
 constexpr bool IsReference = std::is_reference<B>::value;

 template <typename ... Ts>
 constexpr bool IsConstructible = std::is_constructible<Ts...>::value;
```

Comment: mmm I forgot the second argument to enable_if. I added a std::nullptr_t = nullptr (check updated question) but without luck. Now VS tells me that function call is ambiguous.
I'm studying from here: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/05/18/make-sfinae-pretty-2-hidden-beauty-sfinae/

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi - Have you removed the `= 0` after the `ENABLE_IF`?

Comment: I added = 0 in order to support the variadic template pack. I removed it now and used a TWO arguments version of the SFINAE'd methods. Still No luck

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi - Still ambiguous? You have two couples of **alternative** functions; you have to SFINAE enable/disable all of then. Give me some minutes and I expand my answer.

Comment: it's not ambiguous now but it's still giving me "is constructible" message

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi - But you have removed the `nullptr`; you have to add the `nullptr` or defining `ENABLE_IF` or using it. I've tried adding `= nullptr` in the macro definition and (see the extended answer) now I get "Is NOT Constructible!"

Comment: YEP! it worked! Thanks. Would you explain why does that = nullptr (or = 0 in your int example) fix the issue? Furthermore, can this work with variadic template packs?

Comment: I'm sorry.. but now it always says "not constructible" even if I pass a const char* argument :(. This happens only when i'm using variadic template packs

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi - In my toy code, it works. Doubt: the `String` constructor is `private` or `public`?

Comment: All the string constructors are public. I don't know why it doesn't work with variadic templates pack

Comment: @FrancescoRizzi - Sorry: cannot reproduce.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. By the way I updated my answer with a main descrybing my String object (called MY_OBJECT). If you could help me I would be very grateful. The result now is always NOT CONSTRUCTIBLE, and only works with NON variadic template packs. Any idea?